# Recovering password from Autologin in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: firefox, passwords, recovery, autologin

I don't know where to ask. But I want help in recovering password from my G-mail account which is set as autologin in Mozilla Firefox browser. I have access to account but I don't remember password. Is there someone willing to help?

Comment: You can try downloading the desktop client for lastpass. It will automatically find and show you all saved passwords. To be clear, I am not a part of lastpass. I discovered this functionality when I started to use the service.

Comment: You are saying that it will show saved passwords but will it show passwords which are stored somewhere in cookies? When i type gmail.com it automatically transport me to Loading Mygmail@gmail.com screen.

Comment: If the password wasn't saved, I don't think so. Might be worth a shot in case the password was saved at some point?

Comment: I gave it a shot. Unfortunately, it does not work.